# Automatically reset drop down list to display first line (option)

Tags: excel, list, validation, drop-down-menu, dropdownbox

hoping you can assist. Firstly, Pls forgive my lack of understanding as I’m not a programmer and have no real knowledge of VBA. What I am looking for is a piece of code that will reset a drop down list to display the first line (either a piece of code to reset a particular data validation list or a code that does so for all validation lists on a single sheet). To give context, I have been tinkering around with excel upskilling with various functions and formulas. As such, I’ve gone ahead and built a makeshift order/cash payment system for a coffee shop. I have all my data and respective ranges sitting in one sheet and the actual UI in another. In the UI sheet, I’ve created a few validation lists e.g under category coffee, I’ve created a drop down with “cappuccino, date mocha, latte etc” and for pastries a list with cakes, muffins etc. I’ve done this similarly for various other categories and the idea is when I choose from the lists to place the order, A vlookup and hlookup kicks-in to provide me with a price for either a short, tall or grande beverage, multiplied by the number of units. All this I’ve automatically built into a makeshift payment system that incorporates “total due, gratuity, payment, change etc”. At this point is where I get stuck, I’d like to have a button with an assigned macro that clears all lists back to first line once a transaction has been completed. NB: my first line is already built into the list as “Please select...” when either 
list reflects “Please select...”, all my totals are zero. So, the idea is to reset order list for i.e coffee, muffin etc, whether it’s short, tall or grande  and the quantity all back to displaying first line. Can you please help. Ps: Not sure if this helps but my sheet with all the data is named Store Data and the UI sheet which hosts all drop down lists is named Store Compute. One last thing, all my validation lists are not named. Thanking you in advance and I do apologize for the lengthy query. Oh one last thing, would help if the code can be a simple copy and paste into a new VBA module ;-) thanks

Comment: So if you pick item #97 in the DV drop-down, the next time you click the cell the DV would have the current value first rather than at the ninety seventh position??

Comment: if I pick #97 in the dropdown list, it shoots out details including price for my order. once the transaction is complete i.e. everything on the order is rung-up and paid for, id like to reset all drop downs to display the first line item "Please select..." before taking a new order. I would like to do this by just clicking a button with the assigned macro/VBA Code in it)...under one list I would choose for example 1 x cafe mocha and on another 1 x bagel but before starting the new transaction, I would like to have an easy way of getting both drop down lists back to "Select data...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sample that you can adapt to your needs.

I have a DV drop-down installed in cell **A1** that refers to a list in column **G**:

[image]

Note that the first item in the list is `Please Select...`, *(it can be anywhere in the G-list)*

We have similar drop-downs in **A2** through **A10**.  *(these drop-downs can either also refer to column **G** or any other column-list)*

If you are using more than one column-list, make sure each list includes `Please Select...`

Once you have made your selections and processed the data, run this tiny macro:

```
Public Sub resetDVs()
    [A1:A10] = "Please Select..."
End Sub
```

It will restore each of the cells to the desired "starting state" without having to click each one.

**EDIT#1:**

To have the code get the "reset" value from the G-list rather than the internal value, use:

```
Public Sub resetDVs()
    [A1:A10] = Range("G1").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I’ve manipulated the code slightly and it works for the most part. 

I noticed that the code rewrites “Please select…” as a string and not necessarily referencing the actual text in the data range with the same wording. I can live with this however as a result, my price field is no longer giving me a nil value in its currency field i.e. R0,00 but instead it displays #N/A  
PS: If I reselect “Please select…” from the dropdown, the price field changes to the correct output of R0,00.  I’m happy to leave it like this but would be grateful if you can resolve this issue.

Comment: is there a way to have the code point G1 in your example and if so, how do I do so if its on another sheet? iv tried but keeping getting syntax error.

Comment: @VanWilder  **My error**  The code has an extra space between the word `Select` and the three periods................sorry

Comment: Well spotted. I have fixed that issue but it hasn't resolved my errors. Are you comfortable if I emailed you a screenshot or even just the excel sheet to have a look? This entire exercise started out with me trying to clue myself up with vlookups. This led to indexing and hlookups >>> and this ambitious exercise with all its flaws haha

Comment: @VanWilder  See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: My friend - you are a bloody GENIUS. I can't thank you enough...I spent all night and all day searching and searching for a solution on the internet but to no avail....Thank you sir for taking time to help a stranger.

Comment: @VanWilder  You are quite welcome! .....................I can use this approach myself.